# How to access MyViewModel(AndroidViewModel) in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-viewmodel

I recently implemented Room in my android app.
(https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

It works well in **`Activities`**.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWritedSMSViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WritedSMSViewModel.class);
    mWritedSMSViewModel.getAllWritedSMSs().observe(this, new Observer<List<WritedSMS>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<WritedSMS> smss) {
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            if(smss != null) {
                mAdapter.setSMSs(smss);
            }
        }
    });
```

However I can't use the Room in my `BroadcastReciever`

```
mWritedSMSViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(???).get(WritedSMSViewModel.class);
```

The problem is I don't know what argument should be used above code.
I confirmed that `this` and `context` cannot be used as the parameter.

What's wrong with me?

Comment: **ViewModels** can be attached with `Activity/Fragment` *(LifeCycleOwners)* & `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't have any. So simple answer would be you can't.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You shouldn't do that. It's bad practice. Because ViewModels only attached with `Activity` and `Fragment` Only.

One thing possible to achieve your requirements.

Separate your `Room DB` operation from `ViewModel` in a separate `singleton` class. Use it in `ViewModel` and any other place required. When `Broadcast` is received, write data to DB through this singleton class rather than ViewModel.

If you are observing for the `LiveData` in your `Fragment`, then it will update your views too.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I could access my db in `BroadcastReceiver`.

I've just changed some Room functions to public to access those in `BroadcastReceiver`(RoomDatabase  from google guide was already singleton class) and used below code in `BroadcastReceiver`.
`WritedSMSDatabase db = WritedSMSDatabase.getDatabase(context);
                    WritedSMSDAO mWritedSMSDAO = db.writedSMSDao();
                    new WritedSMSRepository.insertAsyncTask(mWritedSMSDAO).execute(writedSMS);`

Comment: Correct one..!!

Comment: How exactly we are going to observe the livedata variable here? do we need to create a var of livedata in activity or fragment and set the value from BroadcastReceiver to it, then we will observe or how it will give me realtime update? @MehulKabaria